# Emulator not connecting to Windows Mobile Device Center after Emulator soft reset

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, emulation, smartphone, wmdc

Am working on smartphone application. And Developing through Emulator (USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator).

But after Cradle  Windows Mobile Device Center does not connect with Emulator. But it was connecting three days ago. After that I do not know why its not connecting...

Its get connected with device but not with emulator now.
I think I did soft reset from Emulator. So after that It got dead or not connected with WMDC.

please help..

Comment: any error messages? Any new updates installed? any changes to the development environment? It stands to reason that if something worked and now doesn't work, then something changed, can you think of anything that might have changed? We really have no way of seeing what is going on with your system. You must provide us with some details for us to be able to help.

Comment: I think that I have soft reset the Emulator and after that this problem start

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just in case anyone is struggling with this, I spent 4 hours of my life trying to get my emulator to connect. The emulator had been connecting to WMDC perfectly from the day it was set up.

It appeared like the emulator was connecting properly but WMDC would just say not connected. I finally came across a comment that pointed out the issue to me. REMOTE DESKTOP. One of the only things different this day was that I was working remotely. WMDC will not connect properly to your emulator if you are using a RDP connection.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I connect to my dev pc via remote desktop and ran into this problem.  None of the below answers worked for me.  The solution for me was to use a different remote control tool instead of rdp.

Answer (score 9):

I ran accross the same issue.   What you need to do is uncradle the emulator.  Go to the Windows Mobile device center and click on Connection Settings.  Change the connections from DMA to a com port.  Save the settings and close the Mobile Device Center.  Launch the Mobile Device Center and change the setting back to DMA and then cradle you emulator.

Comment: how do i install windows mobile device center in windows 7 32 bit. I am getting link for windows vista 32 bit only

Answer (score 2):

1. GO to your Windows Mobile Device center.
2. Click Mobile Device
   setting.Click Connection setting.new pop up window appear.Check
   (Allow connection to one of the following) and select DMA.other
   check box unchecked it.
3. Go to your application i.e Visual
   studio.go to Tools.click Device Emulator manager go to new windows
   appear.select windows mobile 5.0 pocket PC R2 Emulator.Go to Action
   go Connect go you will see green color small start button side of
   windows mobile 5.0 pocket PC R2 Emulator in same windows.Then select
   windows mobile 5.0 pocket PC R2 Emulator.go to action and click
   Cradle.it will connect and show you Windows Mobile Device center
   connected.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting and De-selecting the DMA Connection, worked for me, but I ran into a little problem with this fix, closing the Windows Mobile Device Manager Window does not always close the process!

If more than one wmdc.exe process is running the emulator will show the connected 'user authenticated' message but the device manager window will not show connected.

Just kill off all the offending wmdc.exe processes in the Task Manager, and start Window Mobile Device Manager & bingo :)

Banged my head for more than a couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

I've found more easy solution to fix this. As i am understand after some analysis, this issue happen because emulator thinks that it already connected to PC. Eg. last time you closed emulator, while it was connected and it saved this state and when you try to cradle it, it don't work. Simply go to ActiveSync settings on your emulated PDA device and you will find that it connected, disconnect it and try to cradle it again... It works for me like charm.

This way is much more easy, especially if you're developing on non-admin Windows user as on admin i needed all the time to enter admin's password while changed Mobile Center's settings.