# Windows Mobile emulator network connection on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, wmdc, windows-mobile-emulator

I have been trying for many hours but I can't connect my Windows Mobile 6.5 emulator to the Internet. I have Windows Mobile Device Center driver update for 64 bit systems and also Windows Mobile emulator version for 64 bit systems. I have a NC2000 PCMCIA network adapter enabled in my emulator device configuration, I cradle device in Device Emulator Manager and I tried to disable and enable again DMA connection in Windows Mobile Device Center.

When I cradle device or enable DMA connection I get a DMA connection notification on my virtual device but nothing shows in Windows Mobile Device Center (it doesn't show any connected device). In network settings on Windows Mobile everything seems ok: it shows that I'm connected to the network and I have assigned IP. But when I try to load any page it shows `"Cannot find server or DNS error"`. I've also tried to set DNS address in network settings to `172.16.254.203` / `172.16.254.202` (found these values on the internet) but it still doesn't work.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different things. One is "How to 'cradle' Devcie Emulator Images and the other is how to get a working virtual network card in Emulator Image:

For the virtual network setup look here: http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000241.htm. You need to install a special driver.

For 'docking' (cradle) option download Device Emulator Manager and after starting a Windows Mobile Emulator select 'Cradle' in the context menu of the running emulator inside device emulator manager.

If you have problems with docking, chack that DMA is enabled in WMDC Connection Settings. Also check the option "USB to PC" (Start-Settings-Connections) and ActiveSync Connection setup inside emulated Windows Mobile device.

As you have done changes that may conflict with the desired setup, I recommend you hard reset the emulator image to start with a 'factory' setup.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I tried all of this things. However I thing I know what my problem might be. I work on remote desktop, I readed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490910/emulator-not-connecting-to-windows-mobile-devide-center-after-emulator-soft-rese?rq=1) that makes a problem. Anyone knows how to run network connection in emulator on RDP connection?

Comment: So, you say you are running a remote desktop session and the device is connected to the host or the client? If connected to the host, I ssume the USB needs to be redirected and all software and drivers (Emulator, WMDC) has to reside (being installed) on the host.

Comment: There is no real device, I'm running Windows Mobile emulator on a remote desktop session.

Comment: Ok, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12812532/2466180) is solution that works for me, thanks for help anyway.